# Optimising tabularray tables (tblr and longtblr) for processing speed

Tags: tables, overleaf, performance, tabularray

Normally I'd refrain from doing such optimisations, but I am stuck with Overleaf's time limits on a project with a lot of relevant tables.

Are there some possibilities to make `tabularray`'s `tblr` and `longtblr` environments faster?

Are there some constructions that make those environments particularly slow and that are better avoided?

Creating the tables once as graphics to be included is not really an option because the contents of the tables may change while the document is revised.

Comment: you can keep the tables as separate documents in the project and re-run them on edit so including them as pdf seems a viable option. (the other option is probably pay to get longer timelimit)

Comment: Another option is to store the table in a separate project, then share the output of the project into your main document project. You'll need to "Refresh" the file in the main project when it changes in the separate project though. This may or may not be an acceptable trade-off for you. The approach is similar to what could be done for large TikZ/pgfplots graphics: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_tikz%2C_matlab2tikz_or_pgfplots_figures%2C_so_I%27m_getting_a_compilation_timeout._Can_I_externalise_my_figures%3F#Generating_the_drawings_in_a_separate_project

Comment: (remark) Unfortunately, despite the nice features, tabularray is quite slow for larger tables (on my machine, 400 table entries take 4-5 seconds)

Comment: I am experiencing serious lag issues with `tabularray` too. None of my tables have more than 6 or 7 rows and columns, but there are quite a few of these, resulting in a build time of well over 2 minutes (and frequent things going wrong with @writefile that simply seem to be caused by the amount of time it is taking to build). I've no choice but to revert to `tabular` as it is becoming unworkable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you explain step by step what you mean by your comment? Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @ToivoSäwén if you make a separate document with just a table you get a pdf that you can include with `\includegraphics` so you can do each table as a separate run and apply the overleaf time limit to each table separately not to all of them in one run. (but tabularray is _very_ slow and even a reasonably small table might run out of time

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, that seems like it would take way too long to setup in a way creates a consistent style and formatting for the tables.

Comment: @ToivoSäwén well you always have the option of paying Overleaf to get more time. It's a commercial not a technical problem that you have.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The cost is one thing, but spending minutes on end to compile every time you change a small thing in your file adds up. But I digress... hopefully `tabularray` will receive further optimisation in the future.

Comment: You could give up on tabularray and use the excellent table packages longtable, tabularx, tabulary, ... written by somebody or other:-)

Comment: Well, we wanted to use tabullarray for a purpose (better PDF display of black lines in tables with grey cells). And we had the best possible commercial access to overleaf at the time of writing this document. We succeeded with the approach sketched in my self-answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there some possibilities to make tabularray's tblr and longtblr environments faster? Are there some constructions that make those environments particularly slow and that are better avoided?

1. Don't use `X` columns, since they cause tabularray to measure all cells for another time.
2. Don't use multicolumn cells, since they cause tabularray to measure all cells for another time.

Comment: but `X` columns and multicolumns are *precisely* the reason people use `tabu` and are forced to `tabularray` now, whose slowness compared to `tabu` is **utterly _ridiculous_** for technical documents

Comment: For anyone curious about replacing `X` columns, you can use e.g. `Q[t,wd=0.1\textwidth]` to replicate them with a set width (replace `0.1\textwidth` with the relevant column width)

Answer (score 1):

We deal with Overleaf time limits currently by splitting the whole document in `subfiles` (using the so-named package, and `bibunits` in addition) and compiling the whole document locally. This allows the distributed contributors to work on their respective parts and keeping an eye on the whole document at the same time.